# C# Properties.Settings.Default not working if change Startup Path

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I have always used  `Properties.Settings.Default` for save little settings for users in my application, but some user report problem if move application to another path. My application code:

Form1 Load:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();            
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Save Settings:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["setting1"] = "value1";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Load Settings:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default["setting1"].ToString() == "value1")
    toggleSwitch6.Value = true;
```

This code working perfect but if start application from Desktop save settings, move application to Download and run, application can't load prev settings, why? Its normal?

Comment: You should explain what *move application to Download and run* means.  Settings are not saved in the app folder but the folder location is based on a hash which uses that location

Comment: I run application from Desktop? Now i save settings, after this i move exe to Download folder, start and Settings are not loaded..

Comment: See [Client Settings FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rprabhu/2005/06/29/client-settings-faq/) also may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38429461/1070452